# Can I open a folder in VS Code via the CLI WITH a command to be run on the intergrated terminal?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

When I open a folder from my native terminal, with `code ./workspace` I'd like to add parameters to tell that it should straight-up run a specific command on an integrated terminal inside VS Code itself.

Like `code ./workspace/ --npm build` or `code ./workspace/ && code windowindex=0 --t --npm build`?

Comment: My current workaround for this is to install extensions that auto-start and auto-run things on the terminal when VS code is opened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS Code CLI does not support this AFAIK.

My current workaround is to use `code` to open a workspace normally, then use extensions that trigger on VS Code startup (when the window opens) to create my terminals and runs commands on them.

There are a couple of these extensions, but personally I use [Terminals Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals).

1. Create and save a workspace (ex. *myapp.code-workspace*)
2. On your workspace, create a *.vscode/terminals.json* file

   [image]
3. Define your terminals in the *terminals.json* file (refer to the [extension's page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals) for the syntax). For example, let's say I want to have 1 terminal that will auto-run `npm run start` and 1 terminal that does `git fetch`:

   ```
   {
       "autorun": true,
       "terminals": [
           {
               "name": "NPM",
               "description": "For NPM commands",
               "focus": true,
               "commands": [
                   "cd myapp",
                   "npm run start"
               ]
           },
           {
               "name": "GIT",
               "description": "For GIT commands",
               "focus": false,
               "command": "git fetch -v"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. When you now do `code myapp.code-workspace`, that should open VS Code *and* open the defined terminals (with the focus on the terminal with `focus: true`) *and* run the listed commands:

   [image]

I like this better even if there's a `code --option` to do this, because if I open VS Code "manually" (i.e. by clicking its icon from the dock), then it will also do the same thing. I won't need a separate config/setup.

Answer (score 0):

I went with Itermocil now.
Its an iTerm2 tool to launch a terminal layout with predefined settings.
I can launch 2 split-window terminals in iTerm2 with each opening a visual code project, and running the scripts from the split terminal, not from the integrated vscode terminals now. I like it so far.
https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil